# List all supported cipher suites on client for UWP

Tags: c#, security, xamarin, uwp

I am trying to figure out a way to list all supported cipher suites for the client on a UWP app. Unfortunately the only solutions I have found online was for checking which cipher suites are available for the server you intend connecting to using the SslStream class. Is there a way to retrieve the supported cipher suites on the client without having to connect to a server?

Comment: Unfortunately, It seems like that now has not this API for listing supported cipher suites.Different Windows versions support different TLS cipher suites and priority order.Suggest that you can list them in local file or web service,and getting them when using.The maintenance of the post list data needs to be handled manually.

Comment: Are list of cipher suites installed on windows guaranteed? For example, is a user able to delete/uninstall a cipher suite? I can list the cipher suites inside a local file or web service only if a user is unable to remove them manually.

Comment: Yeah,Gets the list of cipher suites for TLS for a computer.By command Prompt as follow:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/tls/get-tlsciphersuite?view=win10-ps However , user not able to delete/uninstall them.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: May I post them as answer ^.^ Then question can be closed.

Comment: Yes you can post this as an answer.

Comment: Thanks , have done.Remember to mark it. ^@^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, It seems like that now has not this API for listing supported cipher suites.Different Windows versions support different TLS cipher suites and priority order.Suggest that you can list them in local file or web service,and getting them when using.The maintenance of the post list data needs to be handled manually.

Gets the list of cipher suites for TLS for a computer.By command Prompt as follow:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/tls/get-tlsciphersuite?view=win10-ps

However , user not able to delete/uninstall them.